# iPhone Developing - Simulator and iOS Device Difference

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Firstly, im so sorry about my bad English :/

I'm trying to develop a basic iPhone app (TAB VIEW) using with xCode  4.1
In additional, I also used Three20 library in my project to make an image gallery.

Here's my problem, i created all of app then i tested on simulator and everything works fine.
But when i try on an iOS device (iPhone 4), there is nothing on the screen without tab controller. just gallery tab is working but other tabs are not working on device. These other tabs have buttons and imageviews thats all. I could click the tabs but nothing display without gallery tab..

It looks like a .xib view error but i couldnt solve it. 
Whats ur advice? Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Xcode won't send information to your phone that it thinks it already has.  to rule this error out try cleaning your project (PRODUCT --> CLEAN) then delete the app off your phone, and reinstall.  If this fails, try to create a new project and copy your code into it.  sometimes Xcode will mess up your project, especially the .XIB files.

Comment: i tried all of these but doesn't work :/ i'm gonna upload binary to itunesconnect. but im worry about apple will reject it again.. :/ last reject reason is the name of the application. so im not sure about also they can reject it for this display reasons..

Comment: They will definitely reject your app if nothing shows up on the device.

Comment: Never submit until you've done full testing. What's the name of the app? Unless you change it, they'll reject again.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the **target membership** of all the necessary files. If your images, XIBs, etc. aren't being copied to the device, it could cause behavior like this.